# Confused on How to Implement Main Method that Runs Program in Order:

Tags: python, oop, program-entry-point

I am currently working on an inventory system that I have mocked up so far.

This is the following code:

```
import csv
class start_store:


    def __init__(self):
        self.name = self.ask()
        self.options = self.ask_options()
        
    def ask(self):
        while 1:
            name = input("What is your name?\n")
            if name == "":
                print("Ha! You have to enter a name!")
            else:
                print("Welcome to the Shepherdstown Bake Shop " + name)
                return name
        
    def ask_options(self):
        while 1:
            option = input('''What would you like to do? \n1. Add a Item: \n2. Delete a Item:\n3. Edit an Item: \n4. View Inventory \n5. End Program\n''')
            if option == "4":
                print("Here is the following inventory we have " + self.name)
                items = CsvReader()
                items.make_dict_items()
                items.show_available()
                break
            else:
                print("You have to enter a valid option " + self.name)
```

and the second class:

```
class CsvReader:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.result = []

    def make_dict_items(self):
        with open("Items2.csv") as fp:
            reader = csv.reader(fp)
            labels = next(reader, None)
            result = []
            for row in reader:
                row[0] = int(row[0])
                row[1] = float(row[1])
                row[2] = int(row[2])
                pairs = zip(labels, row)
                self.result.append(dict(pairs))
    def show_available(self):
        for item in self.result:
           print(item)
obj = start_store() # create the instance
while 1:
    obj.ask_options() # use the instance
```

From what I understand, I am able to run my code in IDLE based upon the last three lines in my second class, which initialize, and run. The program runs from : asking the user their name -> asking the user what they would like to do -> performing said task-> looping back to ask what to do.

I am confused on how I would implement a main method that runs my current program in that order? I understand how to make a main method, it being `if __name__ == '__main__':` , but what would I put under it? Would I have it run ask() like in the bottom of my lines? How do I add a main method that runs my program in this order in the sense that it is able to run now in IDLE without a main method?

I apologize if I am overlooking something, I am fairly new to Python and OOP.

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 files: one file called `csv_reader.py`, one file called `start_store.py`, and a third called `main.py`. Place your `CsvReader` and `start_store` classes in the appropriate files, and in `main.py` write this:

```
from start_store import start_store
from csv_reader import CsvReader

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    obj = start_store() # create the instance
    while 1:
        obj.ask_options() # use the instance
```

In your `csv_reader.py` file you should remove the code which creates an obj and the while loop - this should only be in the `main.py` file! This new file will include both of your classes (`start_store` and `CsvReader`) and run your main loop. You can run this with `python main.py`. It is worth noting that the file does not need to be called `main.py` (it can be called anything), and both classes could be included in the same file as the `__main__` function, but this is just a simple example of how to separate your classes and then run them in a main loop.

Answer (score 0):

With python whether you should have multiple classes in a file is a matter of opinion rather than a rule. If the classes are small then why not.
So all you need to do is put your if **name** == '**main**': ahead of obj = start_store() ...

If the script is run from the command line to be able to cancel with Ctrl+C I like to use ...

```
def main()
    obj = start_store() etc ...
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:  # handle Ctrl+C
        sys.exit(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)
```